# Customized Tab bar Using xib

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I make Customized Tab bar Using xib I need to know how to Fetch tab bar bottom in to storyboard and I need to know how to autoresize this nib view for all views

**Screenshot:**

[image: My current tabbar look here]

Answer (score 0):

Define a UIView class named MyTabBar and use same class in place of UIView where you want to add your tab bar

```
class MyTabBar: NibView {

}
```

Now, create a superclass called NibView, which will handle everything about the XIB file merging

```
class NibView: UIView {
    var view: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)        
        xibSetup()
    }
}

extension NibView {

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadNib()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.frame = bounds
        addSubview(view)

        // add Constraints
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[childView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["childView": view]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[childView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["childView": view]))
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func loadNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nibName = type(of: self).description().components(separatedBy: ".").last!
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    }
}
```

More details can be found here on how to use a nib
https://medium.com/swift2go/swift-custom-uiview-with-xib-file-211bb8bbd6eb